# Is transit visa required for Antigua for Egyptian citizen?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas, antigua

I am Egyptian and am travelling to Dominica with a connection in Antigua.

Do I need an Antiguan transit visa?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. If you need a transit visa you need to apply for one. Asking the internet isn't going to get you there.

Comment: I think the question is relatively clear, although the English text is clearly from some automated translator.  I edited the question to be readable/understandable and nominated to reopen.

Comment: Are you aware that [there are British Embassy and consulate locations throughout Egypt](https://antigua-barbuda.visahq.com.eg/en/embassy/egypt/) which handle visa applications for Antigua & Barbuda?

Comment: Are you planning on leaving the terminal?

Comment: If you are an Egypt citizen then you do not need a transit visa for Antigua..

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=eg&DE=dm&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=ag&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a valid visa issued
>   by Canada, USA, a Schengen Member State or United Kingdom,
>   visa waiver fee: USD 100.-

So **if and only if** you already have a Canadian, US, Schengen or UK visa (transit visas also count), you do **not** need an Antiguan transit visa.

Otherwise, you must apply for one, which can be done [**here**](https://evisa.immigration.gov.ag/agEvisa-app/)